# Can jib be used without a repository?

Tags: docker, gradle, jib

The normal `docker build` command creates the image locally and does not do an automatic push to a registry.  Is it possible to do the same with jib using the Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`gradle jibDockerBuild` builds and pushes to a local Docker Engine (daemon).

**However**, `jibDockerBuild` followed by `docker push` is very inefficient compared to building and pushing directly to a registry with `gradle jib` due to the limited capability of the Docker Engine API. Likewise, if you are making small incremental changes during development and you have a large base image or dependencies, it's even possible that `gradle jib` followed by `docker pull` is much faster than `gradle jibDockerBuild`. This is because `gradle jib` can upload only those layers that changed (regardless of the order of layers).

FYI, `gradle jibBuildTar` is another Jib task that creates a local image tarball (of either OCI or Docker format).